# How to quickly create a web-service for testing purposes?

Tags: web-services

I have to make a client for a web-service. The web-service is not ready yet. I want to make a web-service server with one mockup method. This method must take one parameter - a collection of objects. The only thing that I have for now is the `xsd` describing the data type for the web-service's method parameter. Here it is

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://localhost/1csite/Contractors" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://localhost/1csite/Contractors">
<xsd:complexType name="Contractor">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Code" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ParentCode" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="Contractors">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Element" nillable="true" type="tns:Contractor"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

How can I quickly make a web-service server with one method taking objects of this data type?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need a temporary server for a not yet complete web service, so you can build a client against the service. If that is the case, and you are comfortable with Linux, you can set up your own Apache web server and use the [Apache Axis2 web services engine](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/index.html), along with your xsd file. Check out the [quick start guide](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html).